# How to scroll in iOS app using selenium-appium

Tags: scroll, selenium-webdriver, appium

How to scroll in iOS application? Scenario is the following: I need to scroll down the page and need to Tap on the iOS app element   I am using Appium with selenium Webdriver ios automation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing you should do:

1. First, find the element and tap on it. This should scroll automatically.
2. Second, in case first one doesn't work. Find the x andy coordinates using inspector and use Driver.scrollTo();

Comment: Driver.scrollTo(); asking for string as parameter , It says invalid if we pass int value in it , any idea?

Comment: yea, just pass the "name" of the element as string wherever to want to scroll.